# Number of bitstrings in a subset having Hamming distance $k$

Tags: combinatorics, bit-strings

Given a bitstring x and a subset $P \subset \{0,1\}^n $. There are $n \choose k $ bitstrings in $\{0,1\}^n $ with Hamming distance $k$. How many bistrings with Hamming distance $k$ are in the subset $P$, in terms of $|P|$? Also tight bounds would be interesting.

Edit:

partiulary I would like to bound for $x,x' \in P$, $\sum\limits_{x \neq x' } H(x,x')$

Comment: Is P arbitrary?

Comment: yes P is an arbitary set whose caridnality is known

Comment: Do you mean Hamming distance or Hamming weight? Distance meaning between two strings.

Comment: I mean the Hamming distance, i.e. the nummer of positions where the two bitstrings differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say anything interesting with respect to $|P|$ unless $P$ has some property. You can both build a subset $P$ where each element has Hamming distance $k$ or, viceversa, where no element has Hamming distance $k$.

Comment: ok but one can still conclude bounds, please see my edit

Comment: @user18722294 your edit is just a reformulation of the original question, it does not change the fact that for arbitrary set $P$  we can't say nothing in relation to $|P|$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean Hamming distance between strings:

Let $p = |P|$. For $p$ bits $b_i$, the maximum Hamming distance $\sum_{b_i \ne b_j} |b_i - b_j|$ is when half are zero and half are one. Suppose there are $k$ zeros and $p-k$ ones. Then the Hamming distance of all pairs $(b_i, b_j)$ is $2k(p-k)$  which is maximized at $k = \lfloor p/2 \rfloor$ to get $\lfloor p^2/2 \rfloor$. For $p$ bitrstrings of length $n$, an upper bound is $n \lfloor p^2/2 \rfloor$.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean with: "Suppose there are  zeros and − ones". So the $b_i$ are bitstrings of length $n$, do you only consider the cases of all one and all zero strings. If they are alternating 0 and 1 this could also maximize the hamming distance.

Comment: would you agree that an lower bound is attained when all differ by one entry, as there are $p^2 - p$ distinct pairs, the lower bound is $p^2-p$?

Comment: To calculate Hamming distance, each bit can be considered independently. The only thing left to do is ensure the bitstrings are actually distinct, which is why this is an upper bound.

Comment: There are (p choose 2) distinct pairs of p bitstrings. You can have 1000, 0100, 0010 for example where p = 3 and n=4. This keeps the requirement of strings being distinct but idk if it's the best lower bound. You need to minimize 2k(p-k) while ensuring the bitstrings are distinct.

Comment: oh I count $(x,x')$ and $(x',x)$ as two distinct pairs, that's why I do not have the factor two.